# Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference JavaScript Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery

**JavaScript Code**

```
function update() {

    var newAmt = 0;
    var newtable = document.getElementById("tbl");

    for ( var i = 0; i < newtable.rows.length; i++) {
        innerTable = newtable.rows[i].cells[0].childNodes[0];

         if ( (innerTable.rows[0].cells[5].childNodes[0].value != "")
                && !(isNotNumber(innerTable.rows[0].cells[5].childNodes[0].value))) {
            newAmt = newAmt + parseFloat(innerTable.rows[0].cells[5].childNodes[0].value);
        } 
    } 
</script>
```

innerTable.rows[0] is throwing exception as  **Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference** in Internet Explorer

But same piece of code is working perfectly in eclipse web browser

**HTML**

```
<table id="tbl">
 <logic:iterate name="editList" property="list" id="editForm">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td></td>
                    <td /></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td /></td>
                    <td></td>
                    <td><html:text  name="Amt" onchange="update()" /></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                </tr>
             </table>
         </td>
       </tr>
 </logic:iterate>
</table>
```

Stuck in this one from past two days. Completely fed up some one help me

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What does this show? `for ( var i = 0; i < newtable.rows.length; i++) {
        var innerTable = newtable.rows[i].cells[0].childNodes[0], val = innerTable.rows[0].cells[5].childNodes[0].value; console.log(typeof innerTable, typeof val,val);
         if (val != "" && !isNotNumber(val) {
            newAmt += parseFloat(val);
        } 
    } `

Comment: val = innerTable.rows[0].cells[5].childNodes[0].value;
 // throwing exception as **Unable to get property '0' of undefined or null reference**

Comment: Please check my updated code in IE - fill some numbers and click the button

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a try at this much simpler an unobtrusive code
Note I removed the inline event handler

```js
function isNumber(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
var fields, newAmt = 0;
// unobtrusive version ignoring table
window.onload = function() {
  fields = document.querySelectorAll("[name=Amt]");
  for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
    fields[i].onkeyup = function() {
      newAmt = 0;
      for (var i = 0; i < fields.length; i++) {
        var val = fields[i].value;
        newAmt += val != "" && isNumber(val) ? parseFloat(val) : 0;
      }
      console.log(newAmt);
    }
  }
};

// fixing your code - not using nodes will help IE too:

function update() {
  var newAmt = 0;
  var newtable = document.getElementById("tbl");
  for (var i = 0; i < newtable.rows.length; i++) {
    var innerTable = newtable.rows[i].cells[0].getElementsByTagName('table')[0],
      input = innerTable.rows[0].cells[5].getElementsByTagName('input'),
      val = input && input.length ? input[0].value : 0;

    if (val!="" && isNumber(val)) {
      newAmt += parseFloat(val);
    }
  }
  console.log(newAmt);
}
```

```html
Just start typing numbers

<table id="tbl">
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="Amt" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="Amt" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="Amt" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="Amt" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
        </tr>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>

<hr>
<button type="button" onclick="update()">Test your fixed code</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

This exception is generated because value of innerTable.rows is either null or undefined. And you are trying to get the 0th index of undefined or null value. Put a null/undefined check before getting value of innerTable.rows.

To verify, you can log value of innerTable.rows in console.

Comment: alert(innerTable.rows.length);  -- This is showing 2.
and it is not throwing any exception when i run on eclipse web browser but in IE it is not working